# No references showing for the shared Xamarin Forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, reference, assemblies, visual-studio-mac

Today I started coding on a Mac, and got myself everything needed to play with Xamarin.Forms.
I imported my last project but in the shared project the assemblies folder is not there in the dependencies one.
I want to add a few assemblies references to my shared project but when I go to the edit references page, there are no assemblies showing. However, if I do it in my Android project, everything is fine.

Comment: A "shared project" is sharing "just code" between any projects that reference that project, you need to add assembly references to the Android/iOS/UWP/NetStd2 projects, not the shared project.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add assemblies to a shared project. It has to be in your Xamarin.Android project. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/ for further details about code sharing.